# Variables are not picked up by in template directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive where I use this template:

```
<ul class="pagination pagination-sm">
<pre>{{pageurl}}</pre>
<pre>{{prevp}}</pre>
<pre>{{nextp}}</pre>
<pre>{{last}}</pre>
<pre>{{limit}}</pre>
<li ng-class="(start == 0) ? 'ng-hide' : ''"><a ng-click="getNewData('{{pageurl}}?start=0&limit={{limit}}')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span></a></li>
<li ng-class="(start == 0) ? 'ng-hide' : ''"><a ng-click="getNewData('{{ pageurl }}?start={{ prevp }}&limit={{ limit }}')">пред.</a></li>
<li ng-repeat="cou in count" ng-class="(start == cou.num) ? 'active' : '' || ((cou.num - (4 * limit)) > start) ? 'ng-hide' : '' || ((cou.num + (4 * limit)) < start) ? 'ng-hide' : ''">
    <a ng-click="getNewData('{{ pageurl }}?start={{ cou.num }}&limit={{ limit }}')">{{ ($index + 1) }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
</li>
<li ng-class="(start == count[count.length - 1].num) ? 'ng-hide' : ''"><a ng-click="getNewData('{{ pageurl }}?start={{ nextp }}&limit={{ limit }}')">след.</a></li>
<li ng-class="(start == count[count.length - 1].num) ? 'ng-hide' : ''"><a ng-click="getNewData('{{ pageurl }}?start={{ last }}&limit={{ limit }}')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></a></li>
```

And trouble is that this code work

```
<pre>{{pageurl}}</pre>
    <pre>{{prevp}}</pre>
    <pre>{{nextp}}</pre>
    <pre>{{last}}</pre>
    <pre>{{limit}}</pre>
```

and this too (Variables are in cycle)

```
<li ng-repeat="cou in count" ng-class="(start == cou.num) ? 'active' : '' || ((cou.num - (4 * limit)) > start) ? 'ng-hide' : '' || ((cou.num + (4 * limit)) < start) ? 'ng-hide' : ''">
<a ng-click="getNewData('{{ pageurl }}?start={{ cou.num }}&limit={{ limit }}')">{{ ($index + 1) }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
```

but here dont work :( the variables are not picked up by... why? I am confused!

```
    <li ng-class="(start == 0) ? 'ng-hide' : ''"><a ng-click="getNewData('{{pageurl}}?start=0&limit={{limit}}')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span></a></li>
<li ng-class="(start == 0) ? 'ng-hide' : ''"><a ng-click="getNewData('{{ pageurl }}?start={{ prevp }}&limit={{ limit }}')">пред.</a></li>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Because of the ng-repeat. I guess it creates new scope and those params are not exposed in that scope. Change all params like this {{ pageurl }} -> {{ $parent.pageurl }}

Comment: in the cycle they work, but in these places there is no `ng-click="getNewData('{{ pageurl }}?start={{ nextp }}&limit={{ limit }}')"` I use a watch in controller for directive... Maybe it is trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Since you are using `pagination-sm` class I assume you use twitter bootstrap. Then `ng-class` should be different.

   ```
   <li ng-class="{'hidden': start == 0}">
   ```

   But even better would be

   ```
   <li ng-hide="start == 0">
   ```
2. I believe in `ng-click` you put expressions.

   ```
   <a ng-click="getNewData(pageurl + '?start=' + cou.num + '&limit=' + limit)">
   ```

   But even better is

   ```
   <a ng-click="getNewData(cou.num)">
   ```

   And you can construct URL inside `getNewData` because you have `pageurl` and `limit` in your `$scope`

   ```
   $scope.getNewData = function(n) {
      var URL = $scope.pageurl + '?start=' + n + '&limit=' + $scope.limit;
   }
   ```

   This way you move logic to your controller.

Try here to test

http://jsfiddle.net/Serhioromano/ods4k4gk/3/